# Automatically make getters for class parameters (to avoid case classes)?

Tags: scala

In Scala, if we have

```
class Foo(bar:String)
```

We can create a new object but cannot access `bar`

```
val foo = new Foo("Hello")
foo.bar // gives error
```

However, if we declare `Foo` to be a `case class` this works:

```
case class Foo(bar:String) 
val foo = Foo("hello")
foo.bar // works
```

I am forced to make many of my classes as case classes because of this. Otherwise, I have to write boilerplate code for accessing `bar`:

```
class Foo(bar:String) {
  val getbar = bar
}
```

So my questions are:

1. Is there any way to "fix" this without using case classes or boilerplate code?
2. Is using case classes in this context a good idea? (or what are the disadvantages of case classes?)

I guess the second one deserves a separate question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use val keyword in constructor to make it publicly accessible:

```
class Foo(val bar:String) {

}
```

As for your question: if this is the only feature you need, don't use case classes, just write with `val`.

*However, would be great to know why case classes are not good.*

In case classes **all** arguments by default are public, whereas in plain class they're all private. But you may tune this behaviour:

```
scala> class Foo(val bar:String, baz: String)
defined class Foo

scala> new Foo("public","private")
res0: Foo = Foo@31d5e2

scala> res0.bar
res1: String = public

scala> res0.baz
<console>:10: error: value baz is not a member of Foo
              res0.baz
```

And even like that:

```
class Foo(private[mypackage] val bar:String) {
  // will be visible only to things in `mypackage`
}
```

For case classes (thanks to @JamesIry):

```
case class Bar(`public`: String, private val `private`: String)
```

Comment: true `val` does save 1 character. However, would be great to know why case classes are not good.

Comment: @Jus12 I've made an edit according to your question, in short -- it is more flexible

Comment: Actually, you can write case class Foo(private val bar: String) to get private fields in case classes

Comment: I would have preferred that to be the default behavior: all parameters are public unless declared private.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the BeanProperty annotation to automatically generate java-like getters

```
import scala.reflect.BeanProperty
case class Foo(@BeanProperty bar:String)
```

Now Foo has a getBar method that returns the `bar` value.

Note though that this is only useful if you have a good reason to use java-like getters (typical reasons being that you need your class to be a proper java bean, so as to work with java libraries that expect java beans and use reflection to access the bean's properties).

Otherwise, just access the `bar` value directly, this is "the scala way".

See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.BeanProperty

Comment: Also in this precise case you could also name the value `getBar`in the first place, but this goes against the scala conventions.

Comment: note - it is 

   `import scala.beans.BeanProperty`

in Scala 2.12

Comment: why a @BeanProperty foo: Long in a case class, it's convereted in a primitive Long when accessing from java by getFoo()?